# Dbcontext disposed exception EF core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I  recently migrated my web application from ASP.net to.NETCore, I have already registered the DBcontext using DI in my startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContextDB>

                (options =>

            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")),
```

....

```
public partial class MyContextDB: IdentityDbContext<USER>, IMyContextDB
```

...

```
   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)

        {

            optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();

               

        }
```

I have also avoided the use of "using" to retrieve data through the context , and I verified that I don't have any call to manually "Dispose()" the context

However I keep getting this exception whenever I reach this part of the application :

```
     public class Licence : ILicence

        {

            private static IOptionsMonitor<LicenceConfiguration> _appSettings;

   

            private readonly MyContextDB _context;

   

            public Licence(MyContextDB context, IOptionsMonitor<LicenceConfiguration> optionsAccessor)

            {

                _context = context;

                _appSettings = optionsAccessor;

            }

public LICENCECODE GetLicenceCode(string key)

        {

            LICENCECODE LicenceCode = null;

            LicenceCode = _context.LICENCECODE.SingleOrDefault(l => l.LICENCEKEY == key);



            return LicenceCode;

        }

}
```

> "Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is
> disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and
> then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your
> application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the
> context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are
> using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection
> container take care of disposing context instances.\r\nObject name:
> 'MyContextDB'."

I've been through every article available on the internet about this exception but yet I can't identify the actual cause of it.

Could you please help me resolve it

The exception is raised specifically when this call is made :

```
  public async Task<LICENCECODE> GetLicenceCode(string key)

        {

            LICENCECODE LicenceCode = null;

            LicenceCode = await _context.LICENCECODE.SingleOrDefaultAsync(l => l.LICENCEKEY == key);



            return LicenceCode;

        }
```

***PS:***  I tried to change the method to async because I thought that could be the cause of the issue but unfortunately it's still happening.

the call to that method is from another Model class

```
validLicence = _licence.CheckLicence(type.Name, ref message, out maxCount);
```

....

and then inside

CheckLicence

```
LICENCECODE LicenceCode = GetLicenceCode(LicenceKey).Result;
```

Comment: What's the scope/life time of `License`? I.e. how are you registering that in the DI framework?

Comment: @Xerillio it's scoped:
            `services.AddScoped<ILicence, Licence>();`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? Or show how you are calling `GetLicenceCode` and how your controller action looks like?

Comment: Could you share what is your `IMyContextDB` and `LicenceConfiguration`?Also which line did you make such error?

Comment: @Rena I have added extra details

Comment: Please remove excessive whitespace from your code.

Comment: It's difficult to say from the code you've posted. But my suspicion is still that somewhere in your dependency hierarchy there's a class with an incorrectly configured lifetime. Such as the class doing the `_licence.CheckLicence(...)` call is configured to be a singleton or similar. If you can't locate which, can you add the list of all your registrations of DI components?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how you are using your `Licence` class, but it might have to do with the lifetime of the request ending before you complete your work in `Licence`. This could for example happen if your controller action is asynchronous.

Try registering the class with transient lifetime instead:

```
services.AddTransient<ILicence, Licence>();
```

Comment: I tried this,  still same behavior, I keep getting the exception